Problems running Wiki.js in Docker with external Postgres DB
I am trying to get a containerized instance of wiki.js accessing an external Postgres DB. I managed to run wiki.js in a non-containerized scenario with a custom config.yml file.
However, if I now try to run same wiki.js version in a docker container, I run into problems. When starting docker with
docker run --name the_wiki --mount type=bind,source=<path_to>/config.yml,target=/wiki/config.yml,readonly ghcr.io/requarks/wiki:latest

I get errors like
Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
2024-08-16T15:39:31.204Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2024-08-16T15:39:31.205Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.303 =====================
2024-08-16T15:39:31.205Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2024-08-16T15:39:31.205Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2024-08-16T15:39:31.623Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2024-08-16T15:39:31.635Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2024-08-16T15:39:31.687Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error:
UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE undefined:undefined
2024-08-16T15:39:31.687Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 1 of 10]
... more of these
2024-08-16T15:39:58.864Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 10 of 10]
2024-08-16T15:40:01.868Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2024-08-16T15:40:01.887Z [MASTER] error: Database Initialization Error: unable to verify the first certificate

I checked that my custom config.yml file is used in the container by introducing an error in it -> the container crashes.
Any ideas? Maybe how to debug this?
